# How can we draw a line parallel $l_1$ and $l_2 $ to that passes of $p$

Tags: geometry

> How can we draw a line parallel $l_1$ and $l_2 $ to that  passes of $p$ ?

[image]

Please help me.

Thank you.$\Large\color{red}{☺}$

Comment: A line can not be both parallel to $l_1$ and $l_2$. You mean a line that passes through the intersection of $l_1$ and $l_2$?

Comment: @newzad:yes.True, But we must pass on this question.

Comment: You can put the center of the circle to origin. Than define the lines such that $y_1=ax+b$ and $y_2=mx+n$. Find the intersection point of $l_1$ and $l_2$ by $ax+b=mx+n$. So you find $I=(x_i,y_i)$. You know $P=(x_p,y_p)$. Define the line that pass through these points .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you called that segments , **lines**, I think you are working in Non-Euclidean geometry (Hyperbolic) and you are using the [Klein's model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami%E2%80%93Klein_model). In this model, especially when you consider $\mathbb R^2$, The points are represented by the usual points in the interior of a circle (unit disk) and lines are represented by the chords, straight line segments with endpoints on the boundary of the disk.

[image]

Here, as you drew two lines and regarding the place of the point $P$. we cannot draw a chord as problem desired. I made some lines for you:

[image]

Note that, as @newzad remarked correctly, if you don't indicate the certain geometry , then your claim, homework or your problem will be absolutely *wrong*.

Comment: Thank you very much$\Large\color{green}{✓}^\color{red}{❀}$@Babak S.

Comment: We cannot make a line passing through the point which is parallel to those lines.

Comment: Excellent, and colorful